# What is the meaning of the following awk script example?

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I have this example

```
BEGIN { print "*** WARNING WARNING WARNING ***" }

/\<[8|9][0-9]%/ { print "Partition " $6 "\t: " $5 " full!" }

END { print "*** Give money for new disks URGENTLY! ***" }
```

I understand most of it, except the following

```
/\<[8|9][0-9]%/
```

Comment: This script is not really correct. What happen if the disk is 100% full? It will not match. Which is not the expected work, I assume. What is more it will request for money even is no line matches. Which is not a nice behaviour... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular expression that will match word-start `\<` followed by `8`, `|` or `9` (`[8|9]` should probably be `[89]`) followed by a digit (`[0-9]`) followed by `%`.

Answer (score 1):

The `BEGIN` block is executed once before any input files are read and just print the literal string `*** WARNING WARNING WARNING ***`. Similarly the `END` block is also only executed once after all the input files have been read and it just print the liter string `*** Give money for new disks URGENTLY! ***`. All other blocks are executed for every-line that evaluate true for the preceding condition.

```
BEGIN { 
    print "*** WARNING WARNING WARNING ***"
}    
/\<[8|9][0-9]%/{                             
    print "Partition",$6,"\t:",$5,"full!"
}    
END { 
    print "*** Give money for new disks URGENTLY! ***" 
}
```

The condition `/\<[8|9][0-9]%/` is regular expression match against the whole line where the regular expression means the following:

```
\<    # Word Start 
[8|9] # Either an 8 or | or 9 (think this should be [89])
[0-9] # A digit
%     # literal percent character
```

Basically if the line contains anywhere in range `80% - 99%` that regexp will match and the following will be printed: the string `Partition` followed by the sixth field on current line, followed by a TAB, followed by `:`, then the fifth field on the current line, and finally the string `full`. The default field separator in `awk` is white-space.

Comment: Ok, I got it! I just wanted to analyse it a little bit. Maybe on a wrong place.. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

If it Matches <80% to <99%, then show the message Partition### Full

Comment: `\<` matches word-start not litteral `<`.

Comment: @Thor: In which regex? awk uses ERE, and `\<` is not word start. It is `^`. Aha! I have read [man gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators) and really, there it is as gawk specific extension!

Comment: Thanks. Now can you tell me what am I doing wrong here
    BEGIN 
    { 
    print "***CAUTION***" 
    }
    df -k /home | awk 'if (int ($5) > 80)
    { 
    print "Partition" $1 "\t:" $5 "full!"  
    }
    END 
    { print "***Disk is full!!!***"}

Comment: Too much to explain in a comment, what you want is: `df -k /home | awk 'BEGIN{print "*** CAUTION ***"}$5>80{print "Partition",$1,"\t:",$5,"full!"}END{print "*** Disk is full!!! ***"}'`

Comment: @TrueY: I hadn't noticed that `\<` was GNU awk specific, good to know. I'll add a gawk tag.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot. Now it keeps saying line 1: syntax error at or near awk. awk: 1: unexpected character '''  similar problem I had before

Comment: @sudo_O: I think this expression has no real sense. What happen if no disk usage is above 80%? It will print `*** CAUTION ***` and then `*** Disk is full!!! ***`. Which is completely misleading. I think the `$5>80` is not correct enough. `int($5)>80` works better.

Comment: @mssim: I assume that You mistyped something. I did a copy-paste of  `sudo_O`'s solution and it does work (almost) well.

Comment: @TrueY yes `int($5)` should be there, but you can't edit comments after 5 mins, As for it making no real sense.. I don't know why you are telling me, it's the OP script I just fixed the syntax. There is no specification.

Comment: just be careful with `gawk`'s lax criteria in terms of what it considers to be "words" - e.g. :::::::::::::::::: :::::::::: : `echo '８95%' | gawk -e '/\<[89][0-9]%/'`  ::::::::
`８95%` ::::::::: this example would strangely pass because `gawk` couldn't recognize the unicode full width variant of the `ASCII` digit `8` (and there aren't any spaces in between them)